# vhosts configuration not working on couchDb

Tags: couchdb, vhosts, couchapp, couchdb-futon

I am facing a curious problem. I have a couchApp hosted on Iris couch. I purchased a domain name from godaddy and set my CNAME (WWW) to my database address on iris couch.When I type my domain name in the browser I get a couch db message

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.2.0"}
```

Now when I try to map my domain name (www.example.com) to vhosts

```
/dbname/_design/dname/_rewrite
```

it does not work.

My rewrites.json is defined as follows

```
[
{
   "from": "/home",
   "to": "_list/listRecentPostsHome/recentPosts",
   "method": "GET",
   "query": {
       "reduce": "false",
       "descending": "true",
       "limit": "10"
   }
}
]
```

When I point my browser to address like this

```
http://www.example.com/dbname/_design/dname/_rewrite/home
```

it works.

However this

```
 http://www.example.com/home
```

does not. I was hoping that the above url would work? What am I doing wrong?

I am guessing that there is some problem with vhosts configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right this was a bit confusing.After talking to the guys at iris couch here

https://getsatisfaction.com/iriscouch/topics/vhosts_configuration_not_working_on_couchdb

I found out that I was entering my domain name incorrectly in the vhosts configuration.There is no need for "**http://**".After changing this to just "**www.mydomain.com**"  it worked.